# iOS Application update with one Localization language removed

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, app-store

I'm working about one application for iOS. Application is already on App Store. But in new version, I have to remove one from Localization languages (Germany). After this, i observed very strange behaviors: When i deploy application on my phone without old version previous application, then everything is okay - if i has iOS set to Germany, application is in English. But when i deploy it when old version is already installed, then application does not show English translation, but only keys form unexisting Germany version ("terms_header" and so...).

My question is: How application will behave, when i send new version to App Store, and users will updates their phones to new version of my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found it. There is the way to check, how application will behave when is updatet from App Store:

1. Remove application from device
2. Generate Archive from old version of your app via Xcode (Product->Archive)
3. Distribute archived application as Ad-Hoc Deployment
4. Repeat points 2 and 3. for NEW version off your application.
5. Put .ipa file with old version of your app into iTune.
6. Install it on you device via iTune and synchronize device.
7. Check old version of application on you device.
8. Put .ipa file with new version of your app into iTune.
9. Press "Update" in iTunes, and synchronize device.
10. Check new version of application on your device.

In this case, my application is works.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the application on any iOS device, it's bundle resources always get updated. However you can test the scenario using 
- Install old application from xcode with localization
- Test if localization is working properly
- Update application with new build from xcode
- Re-test the application by changing language.

During updates only user generated data stay intact and bundle resources get updated.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the application from the organiser and then reinstall it?

Comment: when I remove application and deploy it again, it's work correctly.